# how not to duplicate code in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, racket, code-duplication

well I came across a function that I wrote that uses the same code a few times.

here is an example:

```
(define (get-min&max-from-mixed-list mixedList)

  (if (null? (sublist-numbers mixedList))
      '() 
      (min&maxRec (sublist-numbers mixedList) 
                  (first (sublist-numbers mixedList)) ; this
                  (first (sublist-numbers mixedList))) ; and this
      )
  )
```

In a procedural programing language I wouldve done:

```
   int x =  (first (sublist-numbers mixedList))
   min&maxRec(sublist-numbers(mixedList) , x , x)
```

From my understanding of Functional languages we don't save stuff in the memory and afterwards, we use them. So how can I not duplicate code?

Comment: “From my understanding of Functional languages we don't save stuff in the memory and afterwards, we use them.” Whatever gave you that impression? In any case, it isn’t correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `let` to bind a value to a symbol & use that symbol as often as you like within the `let` body.

The documentation for it & related forms are here: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html

You could use it in your example like this:

```
(define (get-min&max-from-mixed-list mixedList)
    (let ((snm (sublist-numbers mixedList)))
        (if (null? snm)
            '() 
             (min&maxRec snm 
                         (first snm)
                         (first snm))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hey, can you edit in your answer how to do so with functions... for some reason I am not successful with functions... I am only successful with vars